# Is there a way to speed up/batch Google Calendar read/writes?

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am new to Google Apps Script and learning javascript as I go about this project. Over the course of the introductory codelabs I noted the [best practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) to read all the data into an array with one command, perform operations, and then write it with one command.

I understood how to do this working with Google Sheets but how do I achieve this working with Google Calendar? I have come across a few links discussing [batching with Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch) and [Advanced Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) but I didn't understand how to make use of the information.

I basically hope to batch edit events instead of accessing Google Calendar repeatedly in a `for` loop.

```
function deleteMonth() {

  //  Set Date range to delete 
  var today = new Date();
  var firstDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);

  //  read spreadsheet data and get User Info from ss
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var idSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('User Info');
  //Get users from sheet in array of objects with properties from column header in 
  //'User Info' (name, email, year, calName, calID, early, late)
  var userInfo = getSheetData(idSheet);
  var deletedNames = "";
  for (i = 0; i < userInfo.length; i++) {
    var calID = userInfo[i].calID;
    //    if we have calID proceed to delete events
    if (calID) {
      console.time("get events");
      var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calID);
      var events = calendar.getEvents(firstDay, lastDay);
      console.timeEnd("get events");
      //    Delete events and add deleted name to string 
      //    deletedNames     
      for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        console.time("delete event");
        deletedNames += events[i].getTitle() + ", ";
        events[i].deleteEvent();
        console.timeEnd("delete event");
      }
    }
  }
  spreadsheet.toast("Deleted events: \n" + deletedNames);
}
```

Time output from `console.time()`:

[image: Time output from console.time()]

**Other related links which sounded relevant:**

1. [Using advanced google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) (apps script resource)
2. [Google Developer blog?](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Comment: I'm taking a look at those methods. Does that delete method batch the operation and would be efficient to repeatedly call in a loop? Or is it functioning similarly to my code above with events[i].deleteEvent()? 

Because it doesn't seem like I can pass an Event[] to .delete, right?

Comment: @NikhilGupte - Please do not use code snippets for scripts that cannot be run without external dependencies or platforms. Use proper code formatting [Ctrl+K] instead: single backticks (“`”) for one-liners, property names and methods, code fences (“````”) for code blocks. Also please avoid chit-chat in questions, SO is not a forum, it is a Q&A website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows

- You want to delete all events in a month for several calendars using the batch process with Google Apps Script.
- You want to reduce the process cost of above process.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Issue and workaround:

Calendar API can process with the batch requests. The batch requests can run 100 requests by one API call and can process with the asynchronous process. By this, I think that the process cost can bereduced. But, in the current stage, unfortunately, several calendar IDs cannot be used in one batch. When the requests including several calendar IDs, an error of `Cannot perform operations on different calendars in the same batch request.` occurs. So in your case, all events in a month in one calendar ID can be deleted in one batch requests. It is required to request the number of calendar IDs. I would like to propose this as the current workaround.

By the way, as the modification point of your scrit, in your script, the variable `i` is used in 1st for loop and 2nd for loop. By this, all values of `userInfo` are not used. Please be careful this.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, [please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function deleteMonth() {
  var today = new Date();
  var firstDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var idSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('User Info');
  var userInfo = getSheetData(idSheet);
  var deletedNames = "";
  var requests = []; // For batch requests.
  for (i = 0; i < userInfo.length; i++) {
    var req = [];
    var calID = userInfo[i].calID;
    if (calID) {
      var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calID);
      var events = calendar.getEvents(firstDay, lastDay);
      for (j = 0; j < events.length; j++) {
        deletedNames += events[j].getTitle() + ", ";
        var e = events[j];
        req.push({
          method: "DELETE",
          endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${calID}/events/${e.getId().replace("@google.com", "")}`,
        });
      }
    }
    requests.push(req);
  }

  // Run batch requests.
  requests.forEach(req => {
    const limit = 100;
    const split = Math.ceil(req.length / limit);
    const boundary = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    for (let i = 0; i < split; i++) {
      const object = {batchPath: "batch/calendar/v3", requests: req.splice(0, limit)};
      const payload = object.requests.reduce((s, e, i) => s += "Content-Type: application/http\r\nContent-ID: " + i + "\r\n\r\n" + e.method + " " + e.endpoint + "\r\nContent-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n" + JSON.stringify(e.requestBody) + "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n", "--" + boundary + "\r\n");
      const params = {method: "post", contentType: "multipart/mixed; boundary=" + boundary, payload: payload, headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}, muteHttpExceptions: true};
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/" + object.batchPath, params);
      console.log(res.getContentText())
    }
  })

  spreadsheet.toast("Deleted events: \n" + deletedNames);
}
```

#### Note:

- Please use this script with V8.

#### References:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)
- [Sending Batch Requests](https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch)
- [Events: delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete)

Comment: Eek, good catch. Didn't realize that. And agreed, my getData function is simply returning an array of objects from a spreadsheet with the column headers which I think I will make more use from in the function I have to write to actually create the event. 

This was actually incredible but I have many questions (which I've spent most of the day attempting to clarify). I created a test case with 3 calendars and 30 events each and my initial code took 33s whereas yours took 3.5s. My only issue now is that I'm still having trouble understanding it

Comment: I spent most of the day till this point trying to understand some of the syntax and am just now starting to understand the arrow function syntax, string literals (`${expression}`), and the .reduce(accumlator, value, index) [changed the i-->ind not sure if having 2 i's was also something to correct]. 

I think most of my confusion stems from the HTTP request from the point you created payload downward. I don't think I would have been able to come up with that myself.

Comment: I am trying to write a batch write operation to create events and am going to try myself but it would be from modifying your code more than understanding what I'm doing.

Areas of confusion: 
1. Payload variable 
-e.requestBody is undefined, should it be just stringify(e)?
-where is charset-ut8 coming from? 
2. params? I read the links you provided but still am not grasping the batch operation syntax and how you knew I only needed those particular headers (authorization, muteHttpExceptions). 
3. I'm new to working with APIs so perhaps the UrlFetchApp also is throwing me off slightly.

Comment: Sorry for all my confusion, this was super cool so just trying to figure out how I would have known to create the HTTP post batched with individual deletes and all the other text in the request. Will now try the same with creating events.

Comment: @Nikhil Gupte Thank you for replying. About my answer for deleting events in your this question, can I ask you whether your issue was resolved? From your replyings, I couldn't understand about this.

Comment: sorry for the rambling! Yes, the issue was resolved. I was having difficulty understanding the code and did not know where the best documentation was to put that together myself.  
I am in the process of writing more functions to write to the google calendar and may post if I have difficulties in that batch operation as well. From reading [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/performance) I'm wondering if I would need an If-Match to see if I have already created the event and if that's possible.

Comment: @Nikhil Gupte Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When you have an issue in `to write to the google calendar ` and you post it as new question by including the detail information, it will help users including me think of the issue and solution.